# T-SQL - Next row with greater value, continuously

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table described bellow from which I need to select all rows with [Value] greater for example at least 5 points than [Value] from previous row (ordered by [Id]). Starting with first row of [Id] 1, desired output would be:

```
[Id]    [Value]
---------------
  1        1
  4       12
  8       21
```

Code:

```
 declare @Data table 
               (
                    [Id] int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
                    [Value] int not null
               );

 insert into @Data ([Value])
     select 1 [Value]
     union all
     select 5
     union all
     select 3
     union all
     select 12
     union all
     select 8
     union all
     select 9
     union all
     select 16
     union all
     select 21;

select [t1].*
from @Data [t1];
```

Edit:

So, based on JNevill's and Hogan's answers I end with this:

```
 ;with [cte1]
 as (

    select [t1].[Id], 
    [t1].[Value], 
    cast(1 as int) [rank]
    from @Data [t1]
    where [t1].[Id] = 1

    union all

    select [t2].[Id],
    [t2].[Value],
    cast(row_number() over (order by [t2].id) as int) [rank]
    FROM [cte1] [t1]
    inner join @Data [t2] on [t2].[value] - [t1].[value] > 5
    and [t2].[Id] > [t1].[Id]
    where [t1].[rank] = 1

 )

 select [t1].[Id],
 [t1].[Value]
 from [cte1] [t1]
 where [t1].[rank] = 1;
```

which is working. <s>Alan Burstein answer is correct too (but applicable only on MSSQL 2012+ - due to LAG fc)</s>. I will do some performance tests (I'm on 2016 version) and will see performance over my real data (approx. 30 millions of records).

Comment: Why is `16` not part of result ? `16-9 > 5`

Comment: Because it has to be compared to previous founded Value, which is 12.

Comment: For `16` previous value is `9` when we order it by `ID`

Comment: I need to find at least 5 points greater value for the previously founded value. So starting at Id 1, the Value is 1. Next value with at least 5 points greater value than 1 is 12. 12 + 5 is 17, so next available value which meets the requirements is 21.

Comment: so you want to search in order of id?

Comment: Yes, principally. From oldest to newest. It can be DateTime to, I used integer [Id] for simplicity.

Comment: Typically you shouldn't be adding an answer to the question.

Comment: I understand, should I create Answer from my resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way to pull this off is using a recursive CTE. A Recursive CTE is a special type of CTE that refers back to itself. It's made up of two parts.

1. The recursive seed/anchor which establishes the beginning of the recursion. In your case, record with ID=1.
2. The recursive term/member which is the statement that refers back to itself by the name of the CTE. Here we pull through the next record that is greater than 5 from the previous found record according to the ID sorted ascending.

Code:

```
WITH RECURSIVE recCTE AS
(
    /*Select first record for recursive seed/anchor*/
    SELECT 
        id, 
        value, 
        cast(1 as INT) as [rank]
    FROM table 
    WHERE id = 1

    UNION ALL

    /*find the next value that is more than 5 from the current value*/
    SELECT
        table.id, 
        table.value
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) 
    FROM
        recCTE INNER JOIN table 
            ON table.value - recCTE.value > 5
               AND table.id > recCTE.id
    WHERE recCTE.[rank]=1
)

SELECT id, value FROM recCTE;
```

I've made use of the Row_Number() Window Function to find the rank of the matching record by ID sorted Ascending. With the WHERE clause in the recursive term we only grab the first found record that is 5 more than the previous found record. Then we head into the next recursive step.

Comment: you don't need row number -- just TOP 1 would work -- but you can't use [rank] in the where clause without a sub-query.

Comment: also why are you casting ROW_NUMBER() to int?

Comment: I was under the impression that the `TOP` keyword is not allowed in the recursive term in SQL Server. That would be a much nicer way to handle it.

Comment: I haven't tested this workaround to the `TOP` keyword issue, but my guess is that final `SELECT` statement may need to also include `WHERE [rank] = 1` Just to kick out the last iteration's found values. Not 100% certain on that though. Also, to answer the question about `[rank]` in the where clause, I updated my answer to explicitly limit records on the recCTE's [rank]. This is slower, but I think it's the only way to pull it off since subqueries are also forbidden in recursive terms (I think). I don't have a SQL Server to test on and I lack the patience to wait for sqlfiddle.

Comment: Thanks :), I'll try.. There is some syntactic errors in your code, so I will try to modify and run it.

Comment: No doubt about the syntax errors. I'd be happy to edit if there is anything terrible in ther. Also, as @Hogan suggested, that cast to INT for the recursive term's rank is superfluous. I snagged that line from another site when I was investigating workarounds for `TOP` and I'm not sure what they were thinking there. I will remove it now.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on 2012+ you can use LAG which will provide a better performing solution that a recursive CTE. I'm including your sample data so you can just copy/paste/test...

```
-- Your sample data
DECLARE @Data TABLE
(
  Id int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
  Value int not null
);
insert into @Data ([Value])
  select 1 [Value] union all select 5  union all select 3  union all select 12 union all
  select 8  union all select 9  union all select 16 union all select 21;

-- Solution using window functions
WITH 
prevRows AS
(
  SELECT t1.Id, t1.Value, prevDiff = LAG(t1.Value, 1) OVER (ORDER BY t1.id) - t1.Value
  FROM @Data t1
),
NewPrev AS
(
  SELECT t1.Id, t1.Value, NewDiff = Value - LAG(t1.Value,1) OVER (ORDER BY t1.id)
  FROM prevRows t1
  WHERE prevDiff <= -5 OR prevDiff IS NULL
)
SELECT t1.Id, t1.Value
FROM NewPrev t1
WHERE NewDiff >= 5 OR NewDiff IS NULL;
```

Comment: I don't think this will work -- LAG only looks back one row, but he needs to look back 1, 2 and more

Comment: Oops, as I can see now after some other tests, this does not work. Just like Hogan said.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a recursive CTE

```
with find_values as
(
   -- Find first value
   SELECT Value 
   FROM @Table
   ORDER BY ID ASC
   FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY

   UNION ALL

   -- Find next value
   SELECT Value 
   FROM @Table
   CROSS JOIN find_values
   WHERE Value >= find_values.Value + 5
   ORDER BY ID ASC
   FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
)
SELECT *
FROM find_values
```

Comment: There is an problem with subquery: Recursive references are not allowed in subqueries.

Comment: @paYa -- try now.

Comment: Well, TOP is not allowed in CTE's

Comment: Yes, I noticed :)

Comment: There's a "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FETCH'".. I'll take a look into docs, never used FETCH before (except cursors).

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2362/overview-of-offset-and-fetch-feature-of-sql-server-2012/

Comment: It seems, that TOP and OFFSET are forbidden in recursive part of CTE too :(